# Error: Exceeded quota: too many queries per day for this project

Tags: google-bigquery

I believe that the daily quota for non-cached queries is 20,0000 queries a day.

We have run close to 200 queries in a day. I am not sure why we are getting the following error - "Error: Exceeded quota: too many queries per day for this project"

Comment: The 20k [includes](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy) cached queries, does your 200?

Comment: Please share the project name.